# How to restart Windows Store application in Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I want to give user an option to restart immediately to apply different theme, using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/windows.ui.xaml.application.requestedtheme
Retargeting to 8.1 is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to programmatically restart a Windows Store app, and Windows 8 (as opposed to 8.1) doesn't support ThemeResources to apply theme updates to existing controls after they've been created.

You will need to tear down the existing visual tree and rebuild it, but there isn't a good way to do this on the existing page. The easiest way would probably be to navigate away and back.